# Using generic type argument inference with constraint by Enum

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm wondering if I'm cheating, or abusing Generic Constraints in Typescript. By using function overloading you can make typechecking really great.

Lets say you have some animal classes like

```
interface IAnimal {
    legs: number
}

class Fish implements IAnimal { constructor(public legs = 0, public canSwim = true) {} }
class Reptile implements IAnimal { constructor(public legs = 6) { } }
class Bird implements IAnimal { constructor(public legs = 2, public canFly = true) { } }
class Mammal implements IAnimal { constructor(public legs = 4) { } }
```

With function overloading you can return the correct class for typechecking like this;

```
function createAnimal<T extends AnimalType.Bird>(type: T): Bird
function createAnimal<T extends AnimalType>(type: T): IAnimal
function createAnimal<T extends IAnimal>(animal: new() => T): T
function createAnimal(type: AnimalType): IAnimal {
    if(!!arguments[0].prototype && !!arguments[0].prototype.constructor.name)
       return new arguments[0]();

    switch(arguments[0]) {
        case AnimalType.Fish: return new Fish();
        case AnimalType.Reptile: return new Reptile();
        case AnimalType.Bird: return new Bird();
        case AnimalType.Mammal: return new Mammal();
    }
}
```

Since I have said that AnimalType.Bird returns a Bird I may type `createAnimal(AnimalType.Bird).canFly` without any compile error

I came over this after using overloading with constructor inference like above; `createAnimal(Fish).canSwim`

Is using Generic constraints with Enums like this abusement of Typescript?

Comment: I would suggest that `IAnimal` also have `canSwim` and `canFly` properties and just set those to `false` for the animals it doesn't apply to. By the way, some mammals and reptiles can swim and fly.

Comment: It just doesn't make a lot of sense. For example there's no reason to have a generic at all. You can just use the type directly because it doesn't affect the result. Dad said the whole design just looks off and not because of the enum

Comment: @AluanHaddad It makes sense for typechecking where you don't have to cast your result to the type you know it should return. I dont' have to type "(<Bird>createAnimal(AnimalType.Bird)).canFly

Comment: @ExplosionPills yeah, the extra properties is stupid, but each class may have some unique properties that I'm trying to access - if not, there is no point doing the function overloading.